# Expose a view filter that lists usernames of a specific roll in a roll down menu

Tags: views, input-formats

I have a `view` on one of my sites that list a table of content that is connected to (`entity reference`) a user with a specific role.

Is it possible to make an `exposed filter` that lists all users of role X in a roll down menu?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy , add new filter , choose your field (the field which takes the user) , in filter settings limit users to users in your specific roles (1 or more roles could be selected) and then expose filter with equal operator for user , and user can restrict shown content to a specific user .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a quick question, will there be a problem that I have selected to display node data when I created the view? The field that I'm interested in is a reference field to a user (so I guess the roll part is not that important since its already sorted by the user roll when the content was created?) and I can't see to find an option to make it into a roll down menu.....

Comment: No it is OK , you are going to show Nodes so what you selected is right , but you have to select role on your filter because just users with that specific role should be selected or if a user from other role is selected the view will show nothing